# Return DateTime equivalent from ATL control

Tags: c++, winapi, com, atl

I have a task to add a method to an existing ATL control (the code is probably 8 years old), the control accesses a .NET code and retrieve a DateTime value, I want to return this value from my ATL.

Any ideas how to do that ? I tried using COleDateTime but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

[`SystemTimeToVariantTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and friends get you COM compatible `DATE` value accepted by .NET via interop.

```
STDMETHOD(Foo)(DATE* pfValue)
{
  // ...
  SystemTimeToVariantTime(..., pfValue);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more ? is my return value should be SYSTEMTIME?

Comment: Your return value is `DATE` or `VARIANT`. To elaborate more, you need to mention what time/date you have in C++ code, which you want to expose to .NET.

Comment: my return type is DATE, I am trying to use it in VBA not .NET, my control is .NET and my ActiveX control is C++